# Apply a function to multiple values of a hashmap and return the result in an array

Tags: clojure

I have a definition:

```
(def class1 {:people ({:name "John" :age "25"} {:name "Harry" :age "23"} {:name "Peter" :age "24"})})
```

The result I want is a vector that looks like

```
[["John" "25"]
 ["Harry" "23"]
 ["Peter" "24"]]
```

If I call `(map (-> class1 :people) [:name :age])`
then I get the result ("Peter" "24"). Why do I only get the values from the last hashmap and not the others?

If I then call `(into [] (map (-> class1 :people) [:name :age]))`
then I get the result ["Peter" "24"]

What I need to do is run the `into` function again on the other two hashmaps and then put the 3 results into a vector but I don't know how to do this.

My problem is that when I run `(map (-> class1 :people) [:name :age])`, I get the last of the hashmaps. I believe that you have to do something like run a function on each of the hashmaps, one at a time and then each time put that vector into another vector to get the form that I am looking for.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(def class1 {:people ({:name "John" :age "25"} {:name "Harry" :age "23"} {:name "Peter" :age "24"})})
```

defines `class1` as the map:

```
{:people {:name "Peter" :age "24"}}
```

because a list of the form `(a b c)` evaluates `a` `b` and `c` in turn before evaluating to `c`. If you want your map to contain all the maps you need to quote it:

```
(def class1 {:people '({:name "John" :age "25"} {:name "Harry" :age "23"} {:name "Peter" :age "24"})})
```

To extract the values you want from this map you can use:

```
(mapv (juxt :name :age) (:people class1))
```